# The package fglrx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 12.04, drivers, package-management

Wish I was here with good news today but as my luck has it I'm afraid I'm not :(

I recently bought a new graphics card (sapphire HD 7870) and installed it into my system ... went well up to there ...

I tried updating the driver but won't able to in additional drivers.

I then tried this page http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide

now when I try anything this message comes up

```
"The package fglrx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it"
```

I am at the minute downloading (found on link above)

Download the latest Catalyst package.

This package contains both the 32-bit and 64-bit driver.

(I'm on first step) ... slow Internet ... yay +_+

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip
unzip amd-driver-installer-12-8-x86.x86_64.zip
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
```

any pages or info anybody may have shall be greatly appreciated

can provide more information if needs be
Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-29-generic
GNOME 3.4.2

oh and i can't open "additional drivers" now

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to install the driver for your Ati card would be to open **terminal** and type these lines in and hit enter:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo aticonfig --initial
fglrxinfo
```

Now reboot and your card should be working.

Comment: ATI has been AMD now since 2006 lol.

Answer (score 0):

**the `chmod` command was unnecessary**.
After the .run file is unzipped, execute the following commands:

`sudo -s`

`cd [location of extracted .run file]`

`sh amd-driver-installer* --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise`

It will then build 3 packages - `fglrx`, `fglrx-amdcccle`, and `fglrx-dev` after about one or two minutes.

After the ackages have been generated, execute the following code:

`cd [the location of the newly-built packages]`

`dpkg -i fglrx_8*.deb && dpkg -i fglrx-amdcccle*.deb && dpkg -i fglrx-dev*.deb`

... Then delete any 'Xorg.conf's you might have in  /etc/X11/ and run:

`sudo amdconfig --initial`

`sudo reboot`

Then run `sudo amdconfig --initial` again. To double check everything is working, run `fglrxinfo` - Make sure that there is no mention of VESA. The output should look like this:

```
fglrxinfo display: :0 screen: 0 
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: ... And to test out your new driver, install teeworlds `sudo apt-get installl teeworlds`!